# Use jquery var value in html form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to pass the value of currentDate to a REST GET service when Submit button is clicked. Here I don't understand two things.

1. Whether I can put REST service URL on action attribute of form tag this way.
2. Whether I can pass currentDate var value to the web service as a parameter this way.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit1").click(function() {
    var currentDate = $(".selector").datepicker("getDate");
    $("#testForm").submit();

  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <form name="myForm" id="testForm" method="GET" action="http://localhost:8080/LocWebService/rest/tracollect/currentDate">
    Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
  </form>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="submit1" value="SUBMIT" />
</body>
```

Comment: Where exactly is the `.selector` element?  My current thought is that this is a misunderstanding of REST and there is not an issue.  Mainly if you are trying to grab the datepicker value.  That input is inside the form.  Submitting the form will pass it's value on submit.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate

Comment: Took from the above.

Comment: That element is already in the form.  Datepicker when it changes values will set the input in the form to the value that is selected.  This isn't an issue.  Have you actually let the form submit to and seen that the value is not passed?

Comment: @Taplar Doesn't REST expect parameters to be in the URL path, rather than query string? Normal form submission puts it only in the query string.

Comment: No, nothing about REST says that arguments cannot be query strings.  Typically only ids for the domains are included in the url path.  But even that is up to implementation opinions by the system developers. (ex. `GET /myapp/customers/1234` vs `GET /myapp/customers?firstName=Kevin` , the first being a REST endpoint to get customer by their id, where the second one would be a search against the customer domain, not retrieving a specific customer)

Answer (score 0):

No, variables are not expanded in `action` attributes. You can change the attribute in the function.

I've also changed the handler to be on the `submit` event, so you don't need to call `.submit()` explicitly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });

  $("#myForm").submit(function() {
    var currentDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
    $("#testForm").attr("action", `http://localhost:8080/LocWebService/rest/tracollect/${currentDate}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <form name="myForm" id="testForm" method="GET" action="http://localhost:8080/LocWebService/rest/tracollect/currentDate">
    Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
  </form>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="submit1" value="SUBMIT" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Whether I can put REST service URL on action attribute of form tag this way.
> 2. Whether I can pass `currentDate` value to the web service as a parameter this way.

These are very confusing. As mentioned in the comments, you can pass variables in a GET request in a number of ways. This will really depend on what your REST API is expecting. For example, what date format is needed?

```
mm/dd/yy
yy-mm-dd
ddmmyy
```

Then how should it be passed?

```
http://localhost:8080/LocWebService/rest/tracollect?currentDate=06-26-2019
http://localhost:8080/LocWebService/rest/tracollect/currentDate/06/26/2019
```

There are just a ton of ways it could be done that we cannot anticipate. You will need to determine that.

Consider the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  var dF = "yy/mm/dd";

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: dF
  });

  $(".fancy").button();

  $("#testForm").submit(function(e) {
    var dObj = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
    var dStr = $.datepicker.formatDate(dF, dObj);
    var act = $(this).attr("action") + "/" + dStr;
    $(this).attr("action", act);
    console.log("New Action: " + act);
    return true;
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" id="testForm" method="GET" class="ui-widget" action="https://localhost:8080/LocWebService/rest/tracollect/currentDate">
  Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"> <button class="fancy" type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Hope that helps.